# phpMyAdmin issue with specific table cannot edit rows errors with blank where statement

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, easyphp

Subject pretty much says it all. I have as specific table that PMA just will absolutely not let me edit the rows. I cannot use the inline table editor and and I cannot click the "edit" link for any row.

PMA barfs with a bad query error due to the fact that for one, the "where_clause" parameter is empty in the link code, thus causing it to run some query that looks like this: SELECT * FROM `database`.`table` WHERE .... WHERE WHAT?

I have no clue why PMA does not create the edit links correctly. There is most certainly and id column that is unique and set as primary.

I'm using version 4.5.4 on a windows easyphp16.1 set up.

I have tried analyzing, checking, repairing the table with no results.

Does anyone have any idea what the heck would be causing something like this?

Comment: Could you provide the statement you ran and the resulting error

Comment: There is no statement. I click on the table, rows appear. I click edit, I get error mentioned above: There was a problem with your mysql query near '' (ran query was "SELECT * FROM `database`.`table` WHERE") There is nothing after "WHERE" which is the problem. PMA is trying to get the data from the row to load the "edit screen" and failing hard. It should be running something like "SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE primary_column='id_of_corresponding_row_that_was_clicked'"

Comment: All the other tables in the database work fine as far as I can tell. And I have this problem on both of my development machines with this table.

Comment: you can use adminer-4.1.0-mysql instead of PMA.

Comment: Can you export your table structure and recreate the problem at https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master ? Can you post here the SQL to recreate your table structure?

Comment: It's obviously a PMA problem. Do you have error reporting enabled on your server? Checked foreign keys? Tried an older version of PMA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `lower_case_table_names = 2` in your MySql (`my.ini`) configuration? Then your probably encountering this bug:

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11816

You can try downgrading to an older phpmyadmin version e.g. `4.4.15.2` until the bug is fixed.

Comment: Update to the latest version of phpMyAdmin and you should be ok- I just updated to 4.6.6 on OSX Sierra and the problem was solved :)
https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

This is related with the name of the table. I got the same problem on PMA running on OsX Yosemite. Removing the camelCase should solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

1. open file: **PMA/libraries/DisplayResults.php**
2. find private method: **_getModifiedLinks()**
3. in **$_url_params** object, change '**where_clause'** value to **$where_clause.' 1=1'**

Comment: This is very dangerous, because in this case it means just edit any row.