# phpMyAdmin 4.6.1.ERROR: Cannot edit table row with built-in editor

Tags: phpmyadmin

I upgraded my phpMyAdmin (Wamp on Windows 7 x64) to the latest version -  4.6.1. It happened also in previous versions, but I **cannot edit rows** in the SQL tab of PMA, after issuing a simple SELECT statement like this:

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE row_id=19956

Note: row_id **is the primary key** and the Edit button **is present**.

The error message says there is a problem with the WHERE clause (generated by PMA after pressing the Edit button) - which, yes, is obviously void (nothing follows after "WHERE").

Editing is possible (1) in the **Browse tab** of PMA - but imagine the difficulty of getting to record #19956 - and (2) in the **Search tab**, if one searches the record by entering its row_id.

[Same problem reported here, but no PMA Version given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593414/phpmyadmin-issue-with-specific-table-cannot-edit-rows-errors-with-blank-where-st)